# Projection where each pixel in a raster has equal height and width (in km/miles)

Tags: coordinate-system

I'm looking to make a raster image where each pixel has an equal width and height in terms of km/miles. My shapefile is in WGS84, so if I convert that straight to a raster, the pixels in the image closer to the equator will be wider (in terms of miles on the surface of the earth) than the pixels closer to the poles. I'd like to avoid this.

Other distortions are OK - I don't care about angles being preserved as much, for example.

Is there a commonly used map projection that supports this?

Edit: Area in question is USA (continental + Alaska, Hawaii, and Puerto Rico), so it's covering a decent portion of the globe.

Comment: Pretty much *every* projection meets this criteria (notable exception of Mercator). You'll need to **edit** the question to specify a working envelope to get a specific answer (and even then you'll be at the cusp of *opinion-based*)

Comment: I assume working envelope refers to geography being covered... edited accordingly. I realize there may be multiple answers to this question, but I hardly think it's opinion-based... whether or not a projection preserves physical x and y distances for a good portion of the northern hemisphere is a very objective question.

Comment: Quite strictly said, "pretty much every", transverse Mercator and others are quite common. I would search for equal-area projections and first hit will probably be Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection.

Comment: I'm concerned that this isn't really true. While equal-area projections preserve area, many achieve this by distorting things along the X axis in some areas and the Y axis in others. For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_cylindrical_equal-area_projection#/media/File:Tissot_indicatrix_world_map_Lambert_cyl_equal-area_proj.svg

Also, how could this question have been improved to avoid the downvoting? It's a serious question with an objective answer (or answers) from a person who genuinely needs help with a GIS problem...

Comment: Please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand why questions which have multiple equally right answers are not appropriate for GIS SE. Unfortunately, you will not be swamped with potential right answers, because there isn't any projection which is going to have equal width and height (distance) in individual pixels across such a huge swath of the globe.

Comment: @Vince is correct.  It may be useful to see why.  If such a raster existed, you could use it to make a near-perfect map of your region, without any distortion of angle or area.  Such maps are possible in small regions (the size of a state or less). The total amount of error is measured by the total *curvature* enclosed within the region (this is the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem).  Across all of the USA, that curvature is substantial--so you're doomed to failure.  Perhaps if you explained what you're trying to accomplish with these restrictions, we could suggest feasible alternatives.